# A column is missing from the Select Top 1000 Rows result

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a view in my database. When I am applying the *Select Top 1000 Rows* command to it in the Object Explorer in SSMS, the resulting script is missing one column, as you can see in the picture below (the missing column is `BranchCode`).

[image]

I have applied the `sp_refreshview` system stored procedure in an attempt to fix the problem, but it didn't help.

How is this possible and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you positive that the Object Explorer shows the up-to-date column list? Have you tried doing Refresh on the column list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would do as Andriy M said in the comments, try doing a refresh on the view.

If that doesn't work, drop and recreate to a new window. I know the "have you tried turning it off and on again" answer isn't cool. But it's a pretty good catch all.